# Synchronization and Semaphore

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, semaphore

I am Looping through a Map , and i have a number of threads.
the queue in the map contains Actions. my goal is to give every thread an Action to do.. but no 2 threads(or more) can run 2 task(or more) from  one queue
it means every thread is gonna search for a queue , and Lock the Queue some how and check if the queue has actions if yes it runs one of them if  no search for another Queue to run fro them actions.
NOTE: number of Queues can be greater than Number of Threads
  e
I tried to synchronize on the 'Map.Entry'

```
        public void run() {

            while (true) {
                Action<?> act;
                for (Map.Entry entry :ActionMap.entrySet()) {
                   Synchronized(entry)
                   {
                      act =  ((Queue<Action>)entry.getValue()).poll();
                      if (act == null)
                        break;
                   }
                }

            }
            }
```

the problem is that if another thread is searching for an action to do is gonna be stuck in the synchronized Line And Wait for the first thread to finish the task or to finish waiting and  that is not what i want.
i want all of the threads to search for queues if some a thread reaches a queue that another thread is working on just skip it and continue searching

so I digged around and found semaphore  so I reached this

```
Semaphore Gate = new Semaphore(1);



        public void run() {

            while (true) {
                Action<?> act;
                for (Map.Entry entry :ActionMap.entrySet()) {
                   if( Gate.tryAcquire());
                   {
                      act =  ((Queue<Action>)entry.getValue()).poll();
                      if (act == null){
                    Gate.Release();
                    break;

                      }
                      else {
                      act.handle();
                      Gate.Release();
                    }
                   }
                }

            }
            }
```

put the problem with this that  Gate.aquire() is gonna Lock all entries 
it means for 2 diffirent entries and 2 different threads only one thread can access the gate and execute the Action

so finally dose any one have a design pattern that can help me ?
thank you ...

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).  What if you had just _one_ thread that scans the map, and submits tasks to a [thread pool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)?

Comment: i feel I was not clear in the explaination i gave two thoughts and said that they don't give me what i want ... i did that to clearify my problem.. I am not waiting for any one to tell me how to modify my code.  other than that your solution wont help i have entries each entry contains queue in this queue there is an actions the threads job is to find entries(Queues) and execute actions ..with some constrains to know about them u can read above..

Comment: I found a solution for it after all  ..its to modify semaphore... a combination  between semaphore and "syncronized"........thank you any way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `java.util.concurrent` types of map for this. They are thread safe, so you dont need Syncronize.

Synchronize means : the resource(which is synchronized) can't be modified by multiple threads simultaneously. e.g MAP returned by Collections.synchronizedMap(Map) will be a synchronized map and can be modified by one thread at a time, but Concurrent Collections allows multiple threads to access different parts of a collection at a given time, based on the requirement. e.g we have an overloaded constructor for ConcurentHashMap which takes input concurrencyLevel as number of threads which can access the collection simultaneously.

Comment: i kinda cant use the Concurrent Collections  beside that if 2 threads are trying to change the Collection one of them have to wait... but in my case if 2 threads is trying to change two diffrent entries they should not wait

Comment: Thats exactly wats Concurrent Collectoins are for, threads messing the same map =P

Comment: if two threads are trying to get  two different entries one of them have to wait right?

Comment: if there are different entries, no. Concurrent is not lock based, is resource based.

Comment: ConcurrentHashMap is a thread-safe object. No matter how many threads access it at the same time, it will keep the promises. But if two of your program's threads each try put a different value into the map for the same key at the same time, that's a data race. When some other thread later looks up that key, the value that it gets will depend on which thread won the race.